# How do you get the DocuSign Account ID using the API?

Tags: docusignapi

In the DocuSign GUI it shows a number in the top right corner which I presume is the company account ID. If your user is in multiple company accounts then you can switch between these accounts and the number changes. My demo account ID's are 17107 and 1133955.

I cannot find a way to get this ID using the API. I need it because a customer has multiple accounts with the same company name and we need to show the same account ID to them so they can differentiate between the accounts in our GUI like they can in the DocuSign GUI.

With the Credential API I can get the list of accounts for the user but the account ID here is the API account ID which is a GUID, not an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Using a simple [Login](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Login.htm) API call you'll get a list of the user's accounts. Each of the `loginAccount` objects within that list also contains an `accountId` parameter.

Comment: The link is not valid anymore.

Comment: This API method must not be used anymore (that's why the link is not good). Instead, use the [oauth/userinfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) API call

Answer (score 2):

Please see the documentation regarding the login_information REST API call:

[https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Login.htm?Highlight=login_information](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Login.htm?Highlight=login_information)

Comment: Looks like REST is the key, I didn't specify, but we're using the SOAP API and I don't think this ID is available in the SOAP API.

Comment: This API method must not be used anymore (that's why the link is not good). Instead, use the [oauth/userinfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) API call

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the external account number (int) using the Account ID GUID you already have by making a GET call to the following endpoint:

```
{base_uri}/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{account_id}
```

Then search for the key "*externalAccountId*".

References:

1. [User info endpoint reference](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/)
2. [GetAccountInformation | eSignature REST API v2.1](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/accounts/get/)

Answer (score 0):

The old loginInfo API call is no longer used.

Instead, use the [oauth/userinfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) API call to learn which accounts the authenticated user has access to.

**Note:** The oauth/userinfo API call server address is **not** the same as the eSignature API. Instead use https://account-d.docusign.com for development, and https://account.docusign.com for production.

PS those addresses are .com, not .net